# Publishing.publications.genericArtifact not available when upgrading to gradle 5.0 from 4.10.2

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

project.publishing.publications.genericArtifact is no longer available after upgrading to gradle 5.0. I guess this is part of the maven-publish plugin.

This code works with 4.10.2

```
project.publishing.publications.genericArtifact.artifact(project.tasks["tarSingleFolder"])
```

but fails with 5.0 with the error message:

Could not get unknown property 'genericArtifact' for Publication container of type org.gradle.api.publish.internal.DefaultPublicationContainer

Prior to gradle 5.0 genericArtifact was available as a publication without any setup.

How do I set my artifact this way with gradle 5.0?